# joomla 2.5, how to retrive data from database?

Tags: php, sql, database, joomla, module

i want to show data from database on my module front page. To retrive data from database i write this code in helper.php

```
public static function getdb($params)
{
// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Select all records from the user profile table where key begins with "custom.".
// Order it by the ordering field.
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('user_id', 'profile_key', 'profile_value',   'ordering')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('profile_key') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('\'custom.%\''));
$query->order('ordering ASC');

// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on    retrieving data).
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach($results as $value)
{
echo $value;
}
}
```

and my helloworld.php file put this code

```
<?php


// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

// Include the syndicate functions only once
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).DS.'helper.php' );


$hello = modHelloWorldHelper::getdb( $params );


require( JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath( 'mod_helloworld' ) );
?>
```

and tmpl/default.php file code is

```
<?php // no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' ); ?>
<?php echo $hello; ?>
```

but results is blank. nothing show in module page. how to i get data from database? how is the right format to get data from database?

Comment: Your query is selecting all records from the `#__user_profile` table where key begins with "custom." Do any of the keys begin with "custom."? If not then that's why there are no results. Maybe if you could explain the exact data you're trying to retrieve, you will get a better answer. Also, does you're helper.php start with a class?

Comment: yes sir profile_key value is custom.message . insert data by stdClass like this page http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase        and yes my helper php start with this  class modHelloWorldHelper

Comment: Why are you adding extra quote marks? Are they part of the literal string?

Comment: @Elin - No extra quotes added. This was simply taken from the [docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#Selecting_Records_from_a_Single_Table)

Comment: @Lodder hmm the docs are wrong then because quote() escapes by default.

Answer (score 0):

$db->loadObjectList() loads an array of objects, which cannot be echo'ed as a string, try to

```
foreach($results as $value)
{
  var_dump($value);
}
```

OR:

```
foreach($results as $value)
{
  echo $value->user_id;
}
```

Comment: @user3009655 - if `var_dump($value);` doesn't display any results then that means your query is incorrect or there are no results to display for your specific query. As mentioned before, if you actually said what you wanted to get from the database, then it would help.

Comment: for debugging also try to echo your query, and try to execute it in PhpMyAdmin, or something similar. or try echo $db->getError(); to see mysql query errors;

Comment: i just want show data from database to my module page. first i insert data in db table and then want to show inserted data in module page. and this example i got from joomla docs. i just want my inserted data to show module page.

Comment: in the user_profiles  user_id =1001  profile_key = custom.message profile_value = Inserting a record using insertObject()  ordering = 1  this is my data value. how to show this data in module page?

Comment: @Lodder sir my target is to make a data entry module and by help you i make a data entry system with some input field like fname lname email.. ect. and that input field can take data and store into my custom table. its good. now i want to show that data in module page. but i dont know how to do this? for that i visit http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase and try the example. but it dose not work.

Answer (score 0):

in helper.php after $results = $db->loadObjectList(); delete other code and insert this code( you should return value do NOT echo it )

```
return $results;
```

and in tmpl/default.php file do foreach loop

```
foreach($hello as $value)
{
  echo $value['user_id'];
}
```

Comment: @user3009655 change echo $value to echo $value['user_id'] also in tmpl/default.php you can use var_dump($value) to check if there is any value

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `user_id`,`profile_key`,`profile_value`,`ordering`
FROM `pwsha_user_profiles`
WHERE `profile_key` LIKE '\'custom.%\''
ORDER BY ordering ASC
```

Is the generated query from your code.

I'm not sure what query you are trying to run and whether you actually meant this to be the query but I'm betting not.

I'd suggest

```
$query->where($db->quoteName('profile_key') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('custom.%'));
```